# Move prototype code out of master branch with git

Tags: git

The master branch of a new project's git repo contains only prototype/spike code. I'm about to re-start the coding from scratch, now that I have the basic ideas understood.

I want the master branch to be clear of all the prototype code. Ideally the prototype code needs to be moved into a branch so I can still get to it later.

Is it possible to reset master back to before the first commit?
What are the git commands to do this?

Comment: The command is `rm -rf .git; git init`.

Comment: @larsmans, this is obviously not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you create a new branch not sharing any history with your other branches:  [How to create a new empty branch for a new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969050/how-to-create-a-new-empty-branch-for-a-new-project).

Before following these instructions, just rename your existing `master` to `prototype` using `git branch -m master prototype`. Then, when following the linked instructions, use `master` instead of `newbranch`.

Comment: master has already been pushed to GitHub. Will that be a problem when I try to push the new master later?

Comment: Yes and no: The new `master` will not be fast-forward of the current `master` (then `prototype`). Thus, you will need to force the push using `git push <github remote here> +master`. If people are still working on that branch, they will be disturbed by this forced update. You should then also push the old `master` as `prototype` to github such that people may do the transition to the new `prototype` branch.

Answer (score 5):

If you're *really* going to start from scratch, just create a completely new repository. It's possible to have two branches without any common ancestor, but it's not really that useful.

Answer (score 4):

1. From the current `master` branch, make a new branch with your prototype code. `git checkout -b prototype`.
2. Get back to the master branch with `git checkout master`.
3. Remove all the files from the `master` branch with `git rm -rf *`.
4. Commit your changes on the `master` branch with `git commit -m "Removed prototype code"`.

This way, the history will be kept and you can always track in the log when the switch took place.

Comment: Git doesn't let me revert back to the first commit.

Comment: @Andrew Davey, if you want to get to a version where there are no files at all in the project, then just `git rm -rf *` instead of `git revert`.

Comment: Sorry, but `git revert` will not remove any of the history but rather *add* another commit which just has the reverse change of the specified commit. I suspect, you really wanted to say `git reset --hard <hash>` which will move `master` to the state *after* the named commit. This is however no straight-forward route to going back to *before* the initial commit. Also, `reset` will as well cause the new `master` to be non-fast-forward w.r.t. the old `master` and the `push` related comment on my answer holds here as well.

Comment: @Tilman Vogel, indeed, `revert` will not remove the history. I said this is a way to *keep* the history.

Comment: @Radu, still `git revert <commit>` does *not* put the tree state into the state of `<commit>^`. Instead it will put the tree into the state of HEAD with the inverse patch of the changes introduced between `<commit>^` and `<commit>` applied on top. It will only undo the changes introduced in a single commit!

Comment: @Tilman Vogel, you're right, `revert` won't work. I changed the answer to use `rm` instead.

Comment: @Radu, ok, that of course works. Somehow, I think two parallel branches next to each other are a little little bit more useful (because the original prototype branch is not formally merged in already and because the tabula rasa commit is a bit awkward history).