# How to create a new (and empty!) "root" branch?

Tags: git

I would like to define a new "root" branch in this git repository.  By "root" branch I mean a branch that is entirely independent of all the other branches in the repository<sup>1</sup>.

Unfortunately, even the commit (let's call it `A`) at the very base of the repo's commit tree contains a lot of files (this was a repository that was initialized on an already fairly mature project).

This means that even if I gave `A` as the new branch's `<start-point>`, this new branch would not start from a "clean slate", but rather it would contain all the files that were committed in `A`.

Is there some way I can create a completely bare branch in this repository, with `<start-point>` as close to `A` as possible?

---

<sup>1</sup>BTW, this is **not** equivalent to creating a new repo.  Separate repos would be less convenient for a lot of reasons.

---

**EDIT**: OK, this is what I did, based on ***vcsjones***' answer:

```
# save rev of the current earliest commit
OLDBASE=$(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD)

# create a new orphan branch and switch to it
git checkout --orphan newbranch
# make sure it's empty
git rm -rf .

# create a new empty commit in the new branch, and
# save its rev in NEWBASE
git commit --allow-empty -m 'base commit (empty)'
NEWBASE=$(git rev-list HEAD)

# specify $NEWBASE as the new parent for $OLDBASE, and
# run filter-branch on the original branch
echo "$OLDBASE $NEWBASE" > .git/info/grafts
git checkout master
git filter-branch

# NOTE: this assumes that the original repo had only one
# branch; if not, a git-filter-branch -f <branch> command
# need to be run for each additional branch.

rm .git/info/grafts
```

Although this procedure is a bit involved, the end result is an ***empty*** base commit that can serve as the `<start-point>` for any new "clean-slate branch"; all I'd need to do then is

```
git checkout -b cleanslate $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD)
```

In the future I will always create new repositories like this:

```
git init
git commit --allow-empty -m 'base commit (empty)'
```

...so that the first commit is **empty**, and always available for starting a new independent branch.  (This would be, I know, a very rarely needed facility, but it is quite effortless to make it readily available.)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969050/how-to-create-a-new-empty-branch-for-a-new-project

Comment: @Anonymoose: Just for the record (rather than debate): I disagree with your opinion.

Comment: There seems to be a much simpler solution based on `git rebase --onto`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645450/insert-a-commit-before-the-root-commit-in-git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In git, is there a simple way of introducing an unrelated branch to a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384325/in-git-is-there-a-simple-way-of-introducing-an-unrelated-branch-to-a-repository)

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Use the `--orphan` when creating the branch:

```
git checkout --orphan YourBranchName
```

This will create a new branch with zero commits on it, however all of your files will be staged. At that point you could just remove them.
("remove them": A `git reset --hard` will empty the index, leaving you with an empty working tree)

Take a look at the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) for checkout for more information on --orphan.

Comment: Does this essentially create a blank slate? As in, from scratch? Or does it keep all your previous changes, but just not in the git history?

Comment: @ConAntonakos This creates a new branch without a parent. The other branches are unaffected, all their changes are kept.

Answer (score 27):

To add to the accepted answer - [best practice](https://kevin.deldycke.com/2010/05/initialize-git-repositories/) to revert to clean state is to create [an initial empty commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/281545) so you can easily rebase while setting up your branches for posterity. Plus since you want a clean state you probably have committed files that you shouldn't, so you have to remove them from the index. With those in mind you should:

```
$ git checkout --orphan dev2
Switched to a new branch 'dev2'
$ git reset # unstage all the files, you probably don't want to commit all of them
$ git commit --allow-empty -m 'Initial empty commit'
[dev2 (root-commit) a515c28] Initial empty commit
```

Comment: I believe this is not necessary as of 2012 because you can [rebase onto root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309391/265521).

Answer (score 10):

> Is there some way I can create a completely bare branch in this repository.

The actual command to use (with Git 2.28+) is:

```
git switch --discard-changes --orphan newBranch
# or
git switch -f --orphan newBranch
```

[`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) is available from Git 2.23 (August 2019), and replaces the [old confusing `git checkout` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309).

But I would recommend Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), because `git switch --discard-changes --orphan` has been optimized in that version.

See [commit 8d3e33d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d3e33dadd359495e43cb65dfadd775987e3da26), [commit 8186128](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81861288a987c6e05526526fa5dc74d2e2b80a5a) (21 May 2020) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ded44af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ded44afa023c981d803b56f42284ed0597a174ee), 09 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81861288a987c6e05526526fa5dc74d2e2b80a5a): simplify metadata initialization
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>
>   <sup>Reviewed-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>
>
> When we call `init_checkout_metadata` in `reset_tree,` we want to pass the object ID of the commit in question so that it can be passed to filters, or if there is no commit, the tree.
>
> We anticipated this latter case, which can occur elsewhere in the checkout code, but it cannot occur here.
>
> The only case in which we do not have a commit object is when invoking [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) with `--orphan`.
>
> Moreover, we can only hit this code path without a commit object additionally with either `--force` or `--discard-changes`.
>
> In such a case, there is no point initializing the checkout metadata with a commit or tree because
>
> - (a) there is no commit, only the empty tree, and
> - (b) we will never use the data, since no files will be smudged when checking out a branch with no files.
>
> Pass the all-zeros object ID in this case, since we just need some value which is a valid pointer.

Test:

```
git switch master
echo foo >foo.txt
git switch --discard-changes --orphan new-orphan2
git ls-files >tracked-files
# test_must_be_empty tracked-files
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use git 2.23 or above you may be used to [`git switch` and `git restore`](https://github.blog/2019-08-16-highlights-from-git-2-23/#experimental-alternatives-for-git-checkout) instead of `git checkout`. If so, the flag is the same as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15034426/1858327).

```
git switch --orphan YourBranchHere
```