# How to create a git repo without a working directory?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-bare, git-worktree

I use git worktree concept to create multiple working directory. One for each feature and/or bug fix.
So I will create a git clone of a repository once, and then I start creating worktree as needed.

When I clone a git repository, by default a working directory is checked out - main worktree. Which we dont use and unnecessarily takes up space. So I am looking for a way to create a git repo with a working directory being checked out at the beginning.

I tried `git clone --bare <url> ./test-git`

which actually created a git repo without a working directory but I was not able to create a git worktree out of it. I use to throw the following error -

```
bash-4.4 [/user/darshan/test-git] $git worktree add -b test-git-worktree.repo ../test-git-worktree origin/repo
Preparing worktree (new branch 'test-git-worktree.repo')
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'origin/repo'.
```

1. What am I doing wrong?

I went inside the `.git` directory created from `git clone bare` command and found that there was `index` file and `lfs` directory missing.
And these two items will be present in the `.git` directory created from the full git clone.

2. What do these two item indicate?
3. On running what git command will I get these items?

Comment: I am looking at the help from `git worktree` and this is what I see for `git worktree add`: `git worktree add [<options>] <path> [<commit-ish>]`. So you should have the path and the treeish.... but you have 3 params. I wonder what you mean with them.

Comment: Also.... not that I am complaining about your workflow.... it's technically possible.... but why do you create a worktree per feature/bug? It sounds like trying to set up fireworks with an atomic bomb. That is _normally_ carried out using separate branches on a single worktree.... and switching between them.

Comment: I personally use this kind of setup alot. But in my use case I just create a playground worktree elsewhere from a normal git repo, not from a bare git repo like OP. Reason is simply I like to go messy in that playground worktree, and if my boss pop-in to let me do a urgent bugfix, I don't have to first cleanup the playground then check out the master. I just open another folder, that's why.

Comment: @eftshift0 so that format of the command that I have used is -
`git worktree add -b <new_local_branch_name> <path> <remote_branch_name>`

This format closely resembles the one in the git website -
`$ git worktree add --track -b <branch> <path> <remote>/<branch>`

In fact the command that I am using works when I use it with a full git clone command.

Comment: @eftshift0 The reason I take this workflow is - we can continue working on multiple bug fixes and features simultaneously. Say, you have to run some test suite which takes hours to complete, or you trigger a build which again takes long time. So with worktree you can continue working on another issue meanwhile. This is the fundamental use case of worktree inception afaik.

Comment: @hackape At the moment even I am creating worktree from the full git clone (not from bare git repo). The thought that came to my mind is when I have created `n` worktrees for my bugs/features, there are `n+1` worktrees present in my storage (additional one is the main/default worktree). since our codebase is too huge, even an additional worktree cost a huge space. So was thinking of a way to eliminate it when I am not really using it.

Comment: I see your cwd is `/user/darshan/test-git`, is it currently a bare repo?

Comment: yes.
it contains all the git administrative files - `branches, config, description, FETCH_HEAD,  HEAD,  objects,  refs` etc

Comment: OK, I believe the problem is the last argument `origin/repo`, the `origin/` is excessive. Remove it you should be fine.

Comment: @hackape Do you mean to remove `origin/` in `git worktree` command?
If you meant that - then the same command is working when I am using it with full git clone.

Comment: I just experimented and found my earlier explanation was utterly wrong. So just forget what I've said. But yes, I mean that removing `origin/` should work.

Comment: okay, I think using `--mirror` instead of `--bare` would work. Looking at the definition from the link - https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-clone
I am going to try this out and update.

Comment: Yeah, I must've confused `--mirror` with `--bare`.

Comment: Just another idea FYI. If the `n+1` worktree disk usage is the only concern, you can also go with normal git clone, then in your local repo, you do `git checkout --orphan empty_branch`. A bit hacky but solves problem.

Comment: Okay, I am not sure how this command works. I will explore on it. Thanks.

Comment: The explanation is [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---bare). I quote "Also the branch heads at the remote are copied directly to corresponding local branch heads, without mapping them to `refs/remotes/origin/`". That's why `origin/` should be removed.

Comment: And the `--orphan` option explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034390/how-to-create-a-new-and-empty-root-branch)

Comment: An update - using `--mirror` essentially helped me partially achieve what I wanted. ie, I can create a worktree out of it and it doesnt have the default working tree being created. However, I see some side effects like - when I execute the command `git branch`, it executes all the list of remote branch and not the local one. So looks like it is a mirrored copy of the remote repo. I might have to still understand in depth on how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a git repository without a working copy using -

```
git clone -n <url>
```

This just creates a directory (with repository name) with `.git` directory inside it.

*Note*: Furthermore, I hope using git clone --bare should also provide similar functionality. But have not been able to figure that out yet.