# Is there a good reason why working trees should be created at the same directory hierarchy level as the git repo?

Tags: git, git-worktree, git-repo

When I went through many tutorials related to `git worktree`, everywhere in the command which was used to demonstrate the creation of worktree, `..` was used for the path where the working tree should be created - which indicates that the new working tree directory to be created at the same directory hierarchy level as that of the git repo.

An example taken from the [git website](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#_examples)

```
git worktree add -b emergency-fix ../temp master
```

And another from [Atomic Object](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/06/26/parallelize-development-git-worktrees/)-

```
git worktree add ../new-worktree-dir some-existing-branch
```

So I am wondering is there a good reason to create worktree at the same directory hierarchy as the git repo?

Technically, you can create the working tree inside the git repo also. Git allows it.

And I feel creating all the worktree belonging to a particular `git repo` under the git repo directory would give a logical grouping.

```
git worktree add -b emergency-fix ./temp master
```

Comment: If the git repository is non-bare then adding a worktree inside of it can become confusing (I don't know if git knows how to handle it, but even if it does, it's confusing to users). For a bare repository, I see no reason not to create the worktrees inside of it.

Comment: In a non-bare repository, the repository itself is also a worktree. If you create extra worktrees inside it, you need to carefully exclude the worktrees to avoid adding them by mistake. A nested worktree could be confusing with a submodule.

Comment: Got it. So how can I create a worktree out of bare git repo?
A question related to that has been posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64457757/how-to-create-a-git-repo-without-a-working-directory?noredirect=1#comment113978755_64457757

Seems you know on usage of worktree with bare git repo, can you answer the above SO question?

Comment: @DarshanL A bare git repo is designed as a repo without worktrees. Although it's possible to create worktrees for a bare repo, it's recommended to clone a non-bare repository with `-n`. `-n` instructs the repo not to checkout any files, so that its main worktree is empty. And then you can create extra worktrees for refs and revisions.

Comment: @ElpieKay wow... `-n` option with `git clone` works. This is what I was looking for. Great! Thanks. You can answer on that other question, I can accept your answer.