# Rename master-branch and create a new, empty master

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I used the `git subtree` command on an existing repository, in order to extract a subfolder into its own repository. Then, I pushed the extracted commits to its new repository, into the `master-branch`.

However, I should have pushed it into the `"feature/FT001"-branch` all along and wanted to change everything accordingly:

1. renamed the branch: `git branch -m feature/FT001`
2. delete old branch and push new: `git push origin master feature/FT001`
3. reset the upstream branch: `git push origin -u feature/FT001`

At this state, the master branch does not exist anymore locally and at origin.

I would like to add a new (and empty) `master-branch` now. It should look like I have never worked on `master` before (no commits). The history should look like there was a `master` branch, I then created the `feature-branch` and commited everything to the `feature-branch` (and will eventually merge my `feature-branch` into the `master-branch`).

How can I do these last steps?

Comment: You can't: there is no such thing as an "empty branch" in Git. A branch name is a pointer to a commit. There must be a commit for it to point to. (In other words, you must change your problem-statement requirements before you can solve your problem.)

Comment: @torek: How could I deal with it then? Would I have needed to create an "initial commit" on my master-branch in the very beginning and then branched out of it? Is it still possible to do that afterwards, without messing with the history too much?

Comment: That (an initial commit with, e.g., just a README) is one way, but it is not possible to do that with the tool you used. A simpler method is just to pick any existing commit in the renamed branch and call that commit "master". (The obvious choice is the latest commit.) Perhaps even better, simply don't bother with a `master` at all.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to create a new (and empty!) "root" branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034390/how-to-create-a-new-and-empty-root-branch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose your aim is to make it look like all those extracted commits were only in the `feature/FT001` branch and the `master` branch was only initialized.

If you have Git 2.23, You can do this by creating an orphan branch:

```
git switch --orphan master
```

This will stage all your files, so then you will have to unstage them and make an empty commit to that orphan branch:

```
git reset
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial commit"
```

If you have Git 2.28+ you can just do the `switch` and the `reset` on a single command:

```
git switch --discard-changes --orphan master
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial commit"
```