# node_modules keep being pushed with git despite it being ignored and removed

Tags: git

I'm trying to push my local git project into github remote repo. I added node_modules into one commit I made but this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB when I try

```
git push -u origin main
```

then

```
remote: error: Trace: d8e81b49d1b7e109e7b4585cf6b84d574b3888e15cb1b4f858c87c5a0147bc57
remote: error: File node_modules/node-sass/build/Release/libsass.lib is 160.60 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Then I added .gitignore but that doesn't work because the commit was already made

I tried to remove that node_modules from being tracked and commited using

```
git rm -r cached node_modules
```

but it keeps trying to push that when I do git push.

I don't know how to remove node_modules from being pushed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the discussion under [Tirth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11717445/tirth)'s answer:

You can create a new branch and manually add the commits that do not add the node_modules.

Assuming

- you are on branch `master`
- the commit that added the node_modules has the hash `a1a1a1a1`.
- your working tree is clean i.e. everything is committed locally

---

1. Checkout the commit before the error and create the new branch (called `fixed`).
   If `a1a1a1a1` is the first commit on `master`, you'll have to create an orphan branch as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37794837/10875738) instead.

```bash
git checkout a1a1a1a1^
git switch -c fixed
```

2. If the commit contained other things than the node modules, recreate that commit without the node_modules part.
3. Add all the commits after `a1a1a1a1` to the new branch

```bash
git cherry-pick a1a1a1a1..master
```

Once you are sure everything is there, you can delete the master, rename `fixed` to `master` and then (force) push the *new* master branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you just committed your node modules you could do

```
git reset HEAD~N
```

where N is how many commits you want to go behind. In this case I am assuming you want to go one commit behind. Doing this will un-commit your node modules and other things you committed and put them in your working tree. After this just remove the node un-stage node modules from working tree. Now you can commit again with the changes you want.

Comment: It was the first commit with everything with it, I can use that code to go back even before making any commit?

Comment: Yes you should be able to with N=1 @KevinBuguecio