# Make an empty branch via visual studio team services

Tags: git, azure-devops

I don't know how to make an empty branch, whenever I make a branch, all of the 'master' branch items gets putted in the new branch...

Comment: This is a normal and natural thing in Git: in general, a commit tends to be on *many* branches. (This is in strong contrast to most VCSes where each commit is on *exactly one* branch. In Git, a commit can be on one, two, a thousand, or even *no* branches. This is because, in Git, branch *names* are merely moveable labels for one *specific* commit: the commit to which a branch label currently points is the *tip* of that branch. A new branch name is a new label pointing to some commit—usually the current commit. You can pick another commit or use the special `--orphan` option as shown below.)

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio can't do this from its built-in GUI, but you can easily do this from the command prompt.

[image: open command prompt]

Then [the steps are straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13969482/4233593).

> You can create a branch as an orphan:
>
> ```
> git checkout --orphan <branchname>
> ```
>
> This will create a new branch with no parents. Then, you can clear the working directory with:
>
> ```
> git rm --cached -r .
> ```

[image: command prompt output]

Answer (score 0):

A branch is meant to be a fork of the code in `master`. It sounds like you're after a new Repository:

[image: New Repository]

This will be a blank new `master` in a new Repository, with probably a `.gitignore` file.

`master` is only a convention, you can rename your master branch to anything you like.

Comment: in my case i want a blank branch so I can create a pull request from master into it so I can do a code review on existing code.  my solution in the end was to branch off the initial commit as it contained very little.