# How to create an empty master and raise a PR from existing branch

Tags: git

I have a single branch in my repo: develop. Code has already been committed and pushed in there.

There's no master branch in the repo.

I'd like to create a master branch so I can raise a Pull Request into it.

I've already tried two approaches:
1. create the master branch from develop:

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -b master develop
```

The problem here is there's nothing to compare: master and develop are already the same.

2. create the master branch from orphan:

```
git checkout --orphan master
git reset --hard
```

The problem here is the branches have different history and I get:
"there isn’t anything to compare. (branches) are entirely different commit histories"

git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)

How do I create an empty master so I can raise a Pull Request from the already existing develop?

Comment: See this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969050/how-to-create-a-new-empty-branch-for-a-new-project]
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into that. Any idea how to create a PR to a branch with completely different history? That's the challenge of creating an orphan branch.

Comment: Have you tried simply `git branch -b master` ?

Comment: @InfiniteHigh I'm not familiar with ```git branch -b ```. I've just tried it but it fails (error: unknown switch `b'). Any reference to docs/examples would be great, thanks.

Comment: @RootTunes I made a mistake, `-b` is part of the `git checkout` command.  that would cause the branch to be created and checked out in one command.  E.g.: `git checkout -b master`.  `git branch master` would  simply create the branch without checking it out.  Documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch).

Comment: I thought you meant ```git checkout -b``` ;-). The problem with that is master is tracking develop and therefore up to date already. No need to merge and therefore no need for a PR.

Comment: I'm confused by this statement in your post then: "There's no master branch in the repo.", yet you're saying there is a master branch that's tracking develop?  Which is it?

Comment: @InfiniteHigh sorry for the confusion: there's no master in the repo. But if I'd run ```git checkout -b master``` as suggested then I'd end up with one, which will be up to date with develop (so no PR). Hope it's clearer?

Comment: Asking after over 2 years because I'm almost in the same situation: what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 8):

Just create a branch name.  That's all there is to it, really.  Pick some existing commit and make the branch name `master` identify *that* commit.  That's now your `master` branch.

#### There is no such thing as an "empty branch"

There is a problem already, though, because the word *branch* is ambiguous, in Git.  (See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))  When we say "branch", sometimes we mean a *name*, like `master` or `develop`, and sometimes we mean something else.

What Git really stores is a series of *commits*.  Each commit has a unique number assigned to it: a hash ID, which looks like `8dca754b1e874719a732bc9ab7b0e14b21b1bc10` for instance.  You see these in `git log` output.

Each commit holds a complete snapshot of your project, as a set of files (not folders, just files: the folders, if any, will be created as needed to *hold* the files, at the time you run `git checkout`).  And, each commit has a bit of *metadata:* information about the commit, such as who made it, when, and why (its log message), and—crucially—the raw hash ID of the *previous* commit.

It's these raw hash IDs that make up backwards-looking chains of commits.  If we use a single uppercase letter to fake out the hash IDs—this is much more useful for humans but obviously won't work for thousands of commits—we can draw a simple three-commit repository like this:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Here commit `C` is the *latest* commit.  It records that commit `B` is the earlier commit, so we say that `C` *points to* `B`.  Another way to say this is that `B` is `C`'s *parent*.  Meanwhile commit `B` says that commit `A` comes before `B`.  Commit `A` is the very first commit anyone ever made, and therefore has no parent.  This lets the action stop: history starts—or ends, if you're working backwards like Git does—here.

Sometimes, when we say *branch*, we mean the whole series of commits.  This chain of commits, `A-B-C`, starting from the end and working backwards, is a branch.  You direct Git to find the *last* commit, `C`, which then points back to the earlier commit `B`, which points back again.  No matter how many commits there are, we can always have Git start at the end, and work its way all the way back to the beginning, as long as we know which commit is the *last* commit.  But how do we find the last commit?

In this example it's easy: there are only three commits, and we made them use sequential letter names, so obviously `C` is the last one.  But in a real repository, there may be thousands of commits:

```
$ git rev-list --all --count
58314
```

and their hash IDs look totally random.  How do we know which commit is the *last* one?  Furthermore, what if we have a series of commits like:

```
             I--J
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L
```

where there are *two* "last" commits?

#### This is where branch names come in

A branch *name*, like `master` or `develop`, just holds the actual hash ID of the *last* commit that we want to call "part of the branch":

```
             I--J   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- develop
```

By making the name `master` point to commit `J`, we declare that `J` is the *last* commit of the branch `master`.  By making the name `develop` point to commit `L`, we declare that `L` is the *last* commit of the branch `develop`.

Note that commits `H`, and `G`, and `F`, and whatever else comes earlier, are on *both* branches.  This is a peculiar feature of Git: usually, most commits are on *every* branch.  It's only the last few—or few hundred, or whatever—that are only on one or two or ten of the branches.

For a branch name to exist, it *must* point to some existing commit.  You can make commits without using branch names—this is slightly tricky: it uses what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode—but you can't have a branch name unless it points to some actual commit.  By pointing to that commit, that branch name declares that that commit *is* the last commit in that branch.

This is true even if the name points to a commit in the middle of someone else's chain.  Suppose that you *don't* have a master, but *do* have:

```
...--F--G--H--K--L   <-- develop
```

You can now tell Git: *create the name `master`, pointing to commit `H`* by finding the actual hash of H and running:

```
git branch master <hash-of-H>
```

or:

```
git checkout -b master <hash-of-H>
```

Now you have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             K--L   <-- develop
```

Note that the *commits* did not change at all.  You just added the label `master`—a branch name—to remember the hash ID of commit `H`.

#### A branch name remembers the hash ID of one commit, but has another special feature

Now that you have the name `master` identifying commit `H`, you can:

```
git checkout master
```

and then do some work and make a *new* commit.  When you make a new commit, Git packages up a new snapshot of your project and writes that out.  Git adds your name as the author and committer of this new commit, sets up its date-and-time-stamps, and uses your log message as the reason this commit now exists.  Git adds the raw hash ID of existing commit `H` as the new commit's parent.  Git then saves the new commit into the database of "all existing commits", which assigns the new commit its new, unique hash ID.  We'll just call this new hash ID `I`:

```
             I   <-- ???
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- ???
            \
             K--L   <-- develop
```

Now there's the tricky part: having created commit `I`, Git *moves the current branch name* so that it points to the new commit.  Since the current branch *name* is `master`, Git changes `master` so that it points to new commit `I`:

```
             I   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- develop
```

You should ask yourself two questions now:

1. How did Git know that it should move `master` and not `develop`?
2. What happens to existing commit `H`?

The answer to Q1 here is in the diagram: I have attached the special name `HEAD` to the name `master`.  When you use `git checkout` to select a branch, Git attaches this name, `HEAD`, *to* that branch.  That not only tells Git which commit you have checked out right now, but also which *name* needs to be updated when you make a new commit.

The answer to Q2 is not as obvious until you find that there's a general principle of Git, which is: **once a commit is made, that commit is frozen for all time.**  *Nothing* inside any existing commit can ever be changed—not by you, not by Git.  The reason for this is that the actual hash ID of the commit is a checksum of the data inside the commit.  Change any of the data, even a single bit, and you change the checksum—you get a new, different commit, not the original commit after all.  the original commit remains undisturbed.

The files inside a commit are all frozen, read-only, and saved for all time.  They're also compressed, and in a special Git-only format.  This helps keep Git repositories from becoming instantly huge: if every commit saves every file every time—which it does—how will the repository's size not get totally out of hand?  One of the tricks Git uses is that if you're saving the *same* version of a file, it just *re-uses the existing frozen copy*.  It can do that because the frozen copy *can't* change.

(I like to call these frozen, Git-only copies of files "freeze-dried".  The freeze-dried files don't really have names, inside the Git repository: they have hash ID numbers instead.  Note that they have to be thawed out and "rehydrated" into ordinary files for you to use them—the frozen copy is useless for getting any *new* work done.  That's why `git checkout` makes a *work-tree*, where you can do your work.  The freeze-dried files in the commit become normal files in the work-tree, with Git first creating any folders needed to hold them, using the freeze-dried names stored with the commit.)

#### Every Git repository has its own individual branch names

Usually, we use `git clone` to make our repositories, and then send our work back to whichever repository we started with later, with `git push`.  The `git clone` process copies the *commits* from the original repository.  But it doesn't exactly copy the *branch names*.  Instead, it takes *their* branch names—*their* repository's `master` and `develop` and so on—and *renames* them, calling them `origin/master` and `origin/develop` and so on.

Having just made a fresh new clone of their Git, *our* Git has *no* branch names at all!  It has all of their branch names, renamed to our `origin/*` *remote-tracking names*.<sup>1</sup>  But our Git would like us to have a branch—typically `master`, but if they didn't even have a `master`, our Git will pick some other name now, such as `develop`.  As the *last* step of `git clone`, our Git must:

- pick a branch name,
- *create* that branch name in our repository, pointing to the *same* commit as the `origin/name` name, and
- `git checkout` that commit by that branch name.

The name picked in the first step is:

- the name you supplied in your `-b` argument if you said `git clone -b name`, or
- the name *their* Git recommended, if they made a recommendation, or
- `master`.

That last `master` is a special case, used as a sort of last resort.<sup>2</sup>

So, if you clone a repository that only has a `develop`, you'll get your own `origin/develop` name—a remote-tracking name, not really a branch at all—pointing to the last commit in their `develop`.  But then as the last step of `git clone`, your Git will *create* your own `develop`, pointing to this same commit, and then `git checkout develop` so that you're on your one single branch name, `develop`, and have this one commit checked out.

If you now create the new name `master` in *your* repository, you get this:

```
...--o--o   <-- develop, master, origin/develop
```

(with `HEAD` attached to either `develop` or `master`, depending on how you created the name `master`: did you use `git branch`, or `git checkout -b`?).

You can now run `git push origin master` to tell *their* Git: *create a branch name `master` pointing to this same commit as your `develop`.*  What `git push` does is send their Git any commits that you have, that they don't—any commits you've made that they will need for the *create or update some branch name* part—and then asks them, politely, to create or update some of *their* branch names to match some of *your* branch names:

```
git push origin branch1 branch2 branch3
```

has your Git call up the Git at `origin`—at the URL stored under your name `origin`—and send them any commits they need, then ask them to set *their* branches named `branch1`, `branch2`, and `branch3` to point to the same commits that *your* names `branch1`, `branch2`, and `branch3` point-to.  Since they can only do this if they have those commits, your Git will first send them the commits, if they don't have them.  Your Git will not only send them these *tip* commits (for the three branches), but also any *history*—any earlier commits—needed to connect those tip commits to the rest of the commits in their repository.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git documentation calls these *remote-tracking branch names*.  But they're not technically *branch* names.  In particular, if you `git checkout origin/master` for instance, you wind up with a detached HEAD.  So I prefer to just call them *remote-tracking names*, dropping the word *branch* entirely.

<sup>2</sup>If you clone a totally empty repository, with no commits, their Git has *no* branch names, because it has no commits and a branch name requires a commit.  So they don't recommend anything, in this case.  Your Git must then use `master` as *your* branch name.  Of course, *you* don't have any commits either.  So you now wind up with the same peculiar state you have when you create a new, empty repository with `git init`: you're *on* branch `master`, but branch `master` doesn't exist!  You're on a non-existent branch.  Other parts of Git call this an *orphan branch*.  It's a weird state in which your next commit *creates* the branch you're on, so that you can be on it properly, as it were.  Until then, your `HEAD` just records the name of the branch to *create*.

---

#### Review

Here's what you have learned (and need to know):

- Git stores *commits*, which store files, in a frozen Git-only format.  Your Git will extract the files into a *work-tree* where you can see and work with them.  The work-tree is *not* part of the repository database and does not get copied around: only *commits* get copied wholesale like this.  (You can make branch names get copied, but that's one name at a time, not en-masse like commits.)
- The commits are identified by hash IDs.  The hash IDs are unique to each commit.  The `git log` command will show you the hash IDs.  Every Git in the universe must agree on the hash IDs.<sup>3</sup>
- Each commit stores its predecessor commit's hash ID.  These form backwards-looking chains.
- Git uses *branch names* to find *tip commits*.  Each name stores *one* hash ID: the ID of the commit that should be considered the *end* of the branch.  Git works backwards from there.
- History is nothing more than a backwards-looking chain of commits.
- The *commits* are what get shared—what matter most with `git clone`, `git fetch`, and `git push`.  The *names* matter too, because they're how each Git will find its commits, but the *names* are local to each Git: they're not necessarily universal, like the hash IDs are.  In particular, branch names are *expected* to move, over time.
- Branch names *automatically* move to encompass new commits, as you make new commits.  When they do move like this, the existing earlier commits just become part of history.  If you were to move a branch name "backwards"—so that the historical commit becomes the tip of the branch (you *can* do this, we just haven't covered *how*)—it may be very hard to *find* the later commits!  (Do you know their hash IDs?  There are ways to find them, for a while.)
- The word *branch* is ambiguous: when you say it or hear it, think about whether you mean *branch name*, or *some series of commits, starting at the last one and working backwards*.  If someone says *remote branch*, did they mean *the branch name, such as `master`, as seen in **the other** Git?*  Or did they mean *the remote-tracking name `origin/master` as seen in **my** Git?*  These are different names, and may point to different commits!  A branch name in some other Git may *change* between now and the next time you look.  Who has access to that other Git repository, and what are they doing to it right now?

---

<sup>3</sup>There's a future complication coming to Git—no one knows exactly when, yet—in which hash IDs will be renumbered, going from SHA-1 to SHA-256.  Exactly how that will be handled is not yet defined.

Comment: This has got to be the most underrated post in whole of SO. Such a goldmine of information on very specific topic. Loved the clarity in it. Your juniors would be so lucky to have you beside them.

Comment: May I ask what specific resources (books, videos, blogs, etc.) you went through (not necessarily in a short period of time) to be able to provide such an in-depth and clear answer on this topic? Also, is there any communication (written) tips that you'd like to share? Sorry, can't stress this enough: this post is amazing.

Comment: @m01010011: It's mostly hard-won knowledge from dealing with Git for well over a decade now. At some point (2016-ish?) I decided that I needed to de-mystify Git. It's tough as Git itself is constantly evolving, but at least there is some bedrock theory behind it all.

Comment: TBH, it is the most underrated post in whole of SO as m01010011 mentioned.Extraordinary post @torek.Maybe if you put it in a blogpost you will get far better reach

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, the detailed explanations from -torek, was really helpful. Let me summarize the steps you can follow to resolve it:

1. Begin by finding the hash of the initial commit. You can do this through the UI by navigating to the "README.md" file, selecting "Blame," and then clicking on "History." Open the most recent commit and copy the 40-character hash associated with it.
2. Next, execute the following Git commands:

-> git checkout -b master

-> git reset --hard <commit hash copied in step 1>

-> git push origin master

These commands will create a new branch called "master," reset it to the commit specified by the hash obtained in step 1, and push the changes to the remote repository.

Once these steps are completed, you can proceed to the UI and create a pull request (PR) from the "develop" branch to the "master" branch.